# Rails - Params missing when updating unchecked checkboxes (as nil values)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, checkbox, parameter-passing, form-for

I've a problem with some checkboxes in a form, in that when they're submitted unchecked, I get the error `param is missing or the value is empty: user`.

I can't see why it's doing this; in most cases, this problem arises from not having the blank boxes defined in a hidden field, which I've got.

It's worth noting, the checkboxes work perfectly when something is checked.

Here's the checkbox code (`@user` is the standard `User.find(params[:id])`):

```
       <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
          <h2>Add your dietary requirements:</h2>
          <div class="field">
                <% hidden_field_tag "user[dietary_requirement_ids][]", nil %> <!-- a lack of this field often seems to generate this problem -->
                <% DietaryRequirement.all.each do |dietary_requirement| %>
                  <%= check_box_tag "user[dietary_requirement_ids][]", dietary_requirement.id, @user.dietary_requirement_ids.include?(dietary_requirement.id), id: dom_id(dietary_requirement) %>
                  <%= label_tag dom_id(dietary_requirement), dietary_requirement.name %><br>
                <% end %>
              </div>
              <%= f.submit "Update your account", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
        <% end %>
```

When something is checked, the params correctly pass through like this:

```
Parameters: {"user"=>{"dietary_requirement_ids"=>["2"]}, "commit"=>"Update your account", "id"=>"2"}
```

Though when nothing is selected, they incorrectly submit as follows:

```
Parameters: {"commit"=>"Update your account", "id"=>"2"}
```

The frustrating thing is, these checkboxes have worked perfectly for me to date, and today began to throw the error - with no discernible changes that should have affected this.

I've had a little look and can't find a solution to my specific problem out there - any one able to help?!

Thanks all, Steve.

**Edit**

Here's the params from the controller:

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :surname, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :phone, :age, :address, :city, :postcode, :country, { :dietary_requirement_ids => [] })
end
```

And the edit / update actions, in case they're useful:

```
def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @fridge = @user.fridge
end

def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @fridge = @user.fridge
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      redirect_to edit_user_path(@user)
    end
end
```

Comment: Please show us your ``permit`` params method in the controller.

Comment: Sure thing - editing the question to include these now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A tiny edit needed in the end to fix this. The `=` was missing from the hidden field, meaning it wasn't loading into the html. Here's the code fixed, in case anyone visits in future.

```
        form_for(@user) do |f| %>
          <h2>Add your dietary requirements:</h2>
          <div class="field">
                <%= hidden_field_tag "user[dietary_requirement_ids][]", nil %>
                <% DietaryRequirement.all.each do |dietary_requirement| %>
                  <%= check_box_tag "user[dietary_requirement_ids][]", dietary_requirement.id, @user.dietary_requirement_ids.include?(dietary_requirement.id), id: dom_id(dietary_requirement) %>
                  <%= label_tag dom_id(dietary_requirement), dietary_requirement.name %><br>
                <% end %>
              </div>
              <%= f.submit "Update your account", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
        <% end %>
```

You'd think I'd have figured this from my comment in the question. Ah well - all's well that ends well!

Answer (score 1):

You are telling your `params` hash to require a `:user` that is just not there, thus the Exception.

Two not particularly pretty workarounds:

**1.** You can prepend an empty `:user` to your params hash before calling `require` in your controller:

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  private

  def user_params
    params[:user] ||= {}
    params.require(:user).permit( .... )
  end
end
```

**2.** Use a dummy hidden attribute to do that for you. Don't forget to add the `:dummy` to the permitted params list.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :dummy
end

<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
   <%= f.hidden_field :dummy, value: 'i am not empty!!!' %>
<% end %>

class UserController < ApplicationController
  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:dummy, ... )
  end
end
```

Comment: Ah - I see where you're coming from! Out of curiosity, why doesn't `@user` pass to unchecked boxes in the same way it does for checked ones? I am, however, still getting errors with your fixes: your second fix throws the original error, while it's `syntax error, unexpected '=' params[:user] || = {}` with the former. I used a [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes-revised) to get these working and am *certain* they've worked perfectly before. Any other ideas appreciated - thanks for the help!

Comment: Two stupid errors: in the first case, an extra space in the ``||=`` operator. In the second, by providing an empty value, that dummy attribute will be removed from the ``params`` hash ! Also note the correct ERB in the second. Both should work now.

Comment: About the Railscast, that one is ancient. Previous to *strong params** (the permit-require part) anyway. You are using Rails 4 for this one, right? That's your change.

Comment: Ah thanks - I couldn't get this working, but will keep trying. Appreciate the help (again!). The Railscast has been updated for subscribers, and it's been worth the money to me so far... check it out if you get the chance. I've put together a temporary workaround with a link to a method clearing the dietary requirements - if anyone reading this would like the code, let me know as there's more than a comment's worth.

Comment: I know that Railscast (I'm also a subscriber-fun), I was just saying that that particular one is very old and probably outdated, with regards to strong params (which is a Rails 4 thing). What problems did you have with my two solutions? I'm confident that both approaches should work ...

Comment: I just outdated **2.** since I forgot to add ``:dummy`` to the permitted params.

Comment: Hi @dgilperez - sorry for the delay, didn't spot your update. Inadvertently, you've solved my problem, when I was trying to implement the `:dummy`. However, it turns out my error was syntax, merely a missing `=` in the line `<% hidden_field_tag "user[dietary_requirement_ids][]", nil %>`. I'm sure you want to shoot me as much as I want to shoot myself, but that was all that was missing! Thanks for all your help - it was looking up the correct syntax for the dummy variable that flagged this to me. You're a hero for the assist though.

Comment: Glad to help! And yes, I think my answer consist of workarounds, sometimes required, but in this case your answer is the best approach. Cheers!